# Oracle SQL - Convert (Date and Julian Hours) to Julian Hours

Tags: sql, oracle

[image: Table view]

The dates are in gregorian date and the hours are in julian. How do I get the difference between in hours between the two times?

Comment: Please show your data as formatted text, not an image. Why are you storing dates and times in separate columns? Are the dates all at midnight? What result are you trying to get?

Comment: Julian hours? What is that? Do you mean 24-hour clock notation? What is the data type of `DTCOLL`? Date?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your date columns are of the `date` data type, and the time columns are of a string type (`varchar2`), you could do these calculations:

```
select to_char(trunc(hours) * 100 + (hours-trunc(hours))*60, 'fm0000') as hours_minutes
from (
        select (   (dtrecv - dtcoll)
                 + ( to_date(nvl(tmrecv, '0000'), 'hh24mi')
                   - to_date(nvl(tmcoll, '0000'), 'hh24mi')) 
               ) * 24 as hours
        from   sample_demog_view
);
```

When time columns values are `null`, `0000` is assumed. When either one of the date columns is `null` the result will be `null` as well.

#### Explanation

Summary: the inner SQL calculates the number of hours between the two date/times as a fractional number. The outer query converts this number to the 4-digit 24-clock notation. NB: This second step might or might not be needed for you.

`(dtrecv - dtcoll)`: the two time-less dates are subtracted from each other which gives a numerical value representing a number of days.

`to_date(nvl(tmrecv, '0000'), 'hh24mi')`: converts the 24-clock notation to a date/time, but the date part is zero. The same conversion is performed for `tmcoll` and it is subtracted from the first. This gives a numerical value representing a number of days, but it will be a fractional number between -1 and 1.

This gets added to the difference in days we already got, giving a fractional number, still expressing a number of days.

To translate that to number of hours: `* 24`.

The outer query then takes that value and truncates it to get the integer number of hours: `trunc(hours)`

Then the decimal part is taken: `hours-trunc(hours)`. This is multiplied by 60 to get the corresponding number of minutes.

Finally, hours and minutes are added (hours multiplied by 100 to make room for the minutes) and formatted as a 4 digit string. Note that the difference may need more than 4 digits, so the `to_char` format might need to be modified if that is your case.

The reason for the outer query is that I wanted to avoid to repeat the same calculation, so I could just refer to it with `hours`. If there is a better solution that only refers to `hours` once, then there is no more need for this `select` nesting.

Comment: I have a hard time following... if you understood the assignment, if you can explain it to the rest of us perhaps we can come up with a better solution. For example, by `dtrecv+.... ` are you simply doing `to_date(to_char(dtrecv, 'dd-MON-rr') || nvl(rmrecv, ,'0000'), 'dd-MON-rrhh24mi')`?

Comment: @mathguy - this is splitting the 'time' strings into separate hour and minute components and using those for date arithmetic. Not conversion to/from strings. The approach in your comment could be a separate answer? This approach does also assume the dates are all at midnight (which is reasonable, but still...); and it would be nice if it was explained a bit.

Comment: @AlexPoole - it could be if I understood the question!  :)

Comment: @mathguy, indeed the same. I took some of your ideas in an update, while at the same time avoiding that the date `dtrecv` has to be converted to string only to convert it back to date again. I looked into the interval functions of Oracle, but they are quite limited.

Comment: It would be easier to add both times to a fixed date; since it cancels out in the difference, it doesn't matter which date they are added to. Like this:  `(dtrecv - dtcoll) + (to_date('01-01-2000' || tmrecv, 'dd-mm-yyyyhh24mi') - to_date('01-01-2000' || tmcoll, 'dd-mm-yyyyhh24mi'))`. Also, I am not sure the outer query is needed; "difference in hours" doesn't sound like it needs to be put back in a string format.

Comment: Indeed that is a nice improvement: no more need of the `to_date('00','ss')`. As for the second point: I thought to use the same time format as stored in the time columns, since the title of the question says *Julian hours to Julian hours* -- so apparently the same format.

Comment: Thank you for the solution! It works perfect